# coonvert qrcode.image.pil.PilImage to a PIL.Image.Image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, qr-code, customtkinter

How can I convert a `qrcode.image.pil.PilImage` to a `PIL.Image.Image`?

I am using the qr_code lib in combination with the pillow lib and customtkinter...

I tried to use the generated qr_code image in a CTkImage but I got the error:
`ValueError: CTkImage: light_image must be instance if PIL.Image.Image, not <class 'qrcode.image.pil.PilImage'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.get_image()` to get the internal PIL image:

```py
# assume qrcode_img is of type qrcode.image.pil.PilImage
pil_img = qrcode_img.get_image()
# then pil_img is of type PIL.Image.Image
```

Comment: thx it worked! I have not so much experience with PIL.. you are my hero!